# Logstash expect # what is wrong

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

i want send data from kafka topic "test" to elasticsearch index "twitter" via logstash but my confing don't work
error is

> reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 1, column 101 (byte 101) after
>   input { kafka { bootstrap_servers=>\"localhost:9092\"
>   topics=>\"test\"} filter{}  output{ elasticsearch "}

```
input { kafka { bootstrap_servers=>"localhost:9092" topics=>"test"} filter{}  output{ elasticsearch {hosts=>["127.0.0.1:9200"]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're missing out a closing bracket in your `input`:

```
input { 
    kafka { 
        bootstrap_servers=>"localhost:9092" 
        topics=>"test"
    }
}   <---- this bracket was missing in yours

filter{}  

output { 
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    }
}
```

Comment: @DominikBaranec anytime :)